# Java Check if socket is connected to client

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, tcp

I have a server socket connection in a Java application. I have it connected to a client socket connection in a matlab script. I can get it to work fine if I start the server then start the client. But if I disconnect the client and try to start the client again it won't reconnect. How can I detect a disconnection on the socket on the server side, in order to reset the connections.

**Server Side (Java)**

```
boolean ss = false;
 while(true){
    try{
             ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);                  
             Socket socket = listener.accept();
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
             while(!ss){
                  if (files != null){
                    for( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ )
                    { 
                        out.println(files[i].getCanonicalPath());
                    }
                    files = null;

                  }
                 ss = out.checkError();
                }                                                        
}
catch( IOException e)
{}
finally{
    listener.close();
    socket.close();              
}   
}
```

**client side (matlab)**

```
function filenameclient

tcpipClient = tcpip('127.0.0.1',9090,'NetworkRole','Client');
set(tcpipClient,'InputBufferSize',7688);
set(tcpipClient,'Timeout',30);
fopen(tcpipClient);

while(1) 
 if (tcpipClient.BytesAvailable > 0)
  rawData = fread(tcpipClient,tcpipClient.BytesAvailable);
  fprintf('FileName: %s\n',rawData);
 end
end

fclose(tcpipClient);

end
```

I know the `fclose` never gets called, but I call it from the console after the stop the matlab client.

Comment: When the connection is closed on the client side, I can still send data without an IOexception.

Comment: In my implementation here of a server / client, I also didnt get an io exception while writing to the output stream, but I do get -1 back from a read attempt on the input stream server side. This causes me to close the socket, which then throws a socket exception when I try to write. Sorta looked like I was getting an excpetion while writing on a disconnect, but its just because I do my read/writes asynchronously.

Comment: Also it looks as though the blocking taking place on inputStream.read() for my reader thread didnt return on disconnect immediately. It did however unblock the moment I attempt to write to the output stream, instantly returning a -1